# Using a variable in a PivotItem to identify a PivotField (Run-time error '1004')

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to use a variable so that I can Identify the lowest and highest dates in a range and change the pivot chart accordingly when a user enters data and filters the graph by year, month or Quarter. However, I am having issues when it comes to inputting a string into PivotItems to identify the PivotField. When I try to run the code below I get Run-time error '1004': "Unable to get the pivotItems property of the PivotField Class".

The issue arises when I use the following code:

```
Dim Lowest_Date As String
Lowest_Date = "<" & Range("C3").Value
Dim Highest_Date As String
Highest_Date = "<" & Range("D3").Value
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 10").Activate
With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Years")
    .PivotItems(Lowest_Date).Visible = False
    .PivotItems("2021").Visible = False
    .PivotItems(Highest_Date).Visible = False
End With
```

However, when I run the code with the lowest date replaced with the original format it works perfectly:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 10").Activate
With ActiveChart.PivotLayout.PivotTable.PivotFields("Years")
    .PivotItems("<11/20/2020").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("2021").Visible = False
    .PivotItems(">3/25/2021").Visible = False
End With
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on why this would not work?

Comment: Try `Lowest_Date = "<" & Format$(Range("D3").Value,"mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: No this gives the same result, I actually changed the format to Text within the sheet

Comment: What's the result in the Immediate Window of `Debug.Print Lowest_Date`?

Comment: the result is <03/25/2021

Comment: Hmmm - why is it not `<11/20/2020`? "The "Lowest_Date" evaluates as the exact same String " seems incorrect then.

Comment: it was the "highest_date" which had the issue, I think it has something to do with the fact that the 0 infront of the three has been dropped. is there a way of formatting in this way?

Comment: Change the cells back to true dates in the sheet, then use `Format$`.

Comment: I tried Format$(Range("D2").Value, "m/dd/yyyy")"and it seems to work for both numbers without a 0 at the start and number with a 0 at the start e.g. 10 and 03. thank you for the help BigBen